# Hero rescues a minor deity, granted a wish of small value; gets a girl

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

As a high school student just starting in science fiction, I read a short story collection in paperback that included this story – not quite a short-short, but not very long either.  I think that it was written by a familiar author, since the collection was one of those “Best Of…” anthologies.

Our hero is a sympathetic young guy trying to get ahead, in love with a beautiful neighbor, but hopeless in love.  He rescues a miniature Minor Deity (and I've forgotten the mechanism – rescued from a cat perhaps?) and gets a wish in return.  The catch is that since this is only a minor deity, the value of the wish is small – and I forget the actual value, perhaps $2.49.  He asks for help winning at the races to help get the girl – and the minor deity says sure, but the payoff can only be $2.49.  How about help rescuing her from a calamity like an earthquake?  Sure, but the total damage can only be $2.49. Other alternatives are discussed, but the value can only be $2.49. Frustrated, our hero thinks about the problem, but the Minor Deity thinks he has a solution.

Later that evening, the girl knocks on the door, he opens it to her welcoming arms, and the night passes.  The next morning, our hero finds a small clipping on the floor, an article stating the latest estimates of the total value of the elements in the human body were… $2.49.  (The whole story was building to that punch line.)

Answer (score 40):

["$1.98"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56754), a short story by [Arthur Porges](http://www.sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/porges_arthur), first published in [*The Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction*, May 1954](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?61289), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v006n05_1954-05_AK/Fantasy__Science_Fiction_v006n05_1954-05_AK#page/n91/mode/2up).

**As a high school student just starting in science fiction, I read a short story collection in paperback that included this story -- not quite a short-short, but not very long either. I think that it was written by a familiar author, since the collection was one of those 'Best Of .." anthologies.**

Three and a half pages in its original magazine publication. Arthur Porges has a [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_Porges); probably his most famous stories are ["The Ruum"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ruum) and ["The Devil and Simon Flagg"](http://kasmana.people.cofc.edu/MATHFICT/mfview.php?callnumber=mf97).

**Our Hero is a sympathetic young guy trying to get ahead, in love with a beautiful neighbor, but hopeless in love.**

> That morning Will Howard was taking a Sunday stroll through the woods, a pleasure which lately had been shared and intensified by Rita Henry. Not even the bright sun, the bracing air, the unique song of a canyon wren, could lighten Will's dark thoughts. Right now she was out riding with Harley Thompson at an exclusive country club. Will couldn't blame her. Harley was six feet two, a former Princeton tackle; ruggedly handsome, full of pleasant small talk; the young-executive-with-a-big-future. And he, Will Howard, a skinny, tongue tied fellow—

**He rescues a miniature Minor Deity (and I've forgotten the mechanism - rescued from a cat perhaps?)**

It was a weasel:

> Quickly Will scooped the terrified rodent into one palm. The weasel stopped, making a nasty, chikkering sound, eyes red in the triangular mask of ferocity that was its face. For a heartbeat it seemed about to attack its giant opponent, but as Will stepped forward, shouting, the beast, chattering with rage, undulated off the path.

**and gets a wish in return.**

> In a voice which although faint was surprisingly resonant, the figure said: "Accept, O kindly mortal, the grateful thanks of Eep, the God. How can I reward you for saving me from that rapacious monster?"

**The catch is that since this is only a minor deity, the value of the wish is small - and I forget the actual value, perhaps $2.49.**

> "You mentioned a—a reward," he said diffidently.
>
> "I certainly did," the god assured him, swinging on a dandelion stem and kicking minute bare feet luxuriously. "But alas, only a small one. I am, as you see, a very small god."
>
> "Oh," Will said, rather crestfallen. Then brightening: "May I suggest that a *small* fortune—?" Truly the presence of an immortal was sharpening his wits.
>
> "Of course. But it would have to be exceedingly small. I couldn't go above $1.98."

**Later that evening, the girl knocks on the door, he opens it to her welcoming arms, and the night passes. The next morning, Our Hero finds a small clipping on the floor, an article stating the latest estimates of the total value of the elements in the human body were... $2.49. (The whole story was building to that punch line.)**

> The next morning, when she picked up the wispy panties from the floor where they had been tossed in flattering haste, a scrap of paper dropped from the black nylon.
>
> Wondering, Will picked it up. It was a newspaper clipping. Someone had written in the margin in a tiny, flowing script: "A gratuity from the grateful (up to $1.98) God Eep."
>
> The clipping itself, a mere filler, read: "At present prices, the value of the chemical compounds which make up the human body is only $1.98."

Comment: Remarkable answer - thanks so much for answering this question that I have had for years!

Comment: @user26586 If this is the book you're looking for, please accept his answer.