# Short story id: Man Meets Stingy Genie

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

It's a few decades old, about a man interacting with a genie. The genie was not very powerful, and could only grant wishes with a cash value of something like $1.97.

And eventually, the man figures out something he wants he can actually wish for...

Comment: Welcome to the site! Great start. Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and see if you can edit in any more details.

Comment: If that isn't it, it's close enough!  Now I just have to figure out in which anthology or magazine I read it.  So...where is this check mark?  I don't see one.

Comment: Any of [these covers](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?56754) look familiar?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a god, not a genie; his limit is $1.98, not $1.97; and it's the god who figures out how to make the man happy for only $1.98. The story is ["$1.98"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56754) by [Arthur Porges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_Porges), also the answer to the old question [Hero rescues a minor deity, granted a wish of small value; gets a [SPOILER]](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/56917/hero-rescues-a-minor-deity-granted-a-wish-of-small-value-gets-a-girl). It was first published in [*The Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction*, May 1954](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?61289), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v006n05_1954-05_AK/Fantasy__Science_Fiction_v006n05_1954-05_AK#page/n91/mode/2up).

> "You mentioned a—a reward," he said diffidently.
>
> "I certainly did," the god answered him, swinging on a dandelion stem and kicking minute bare feet luxuriously. "But, alas, only a small one. I am, as you see, a very small god."
>
> "Oh," Will said, rather crestfallen. Then brightening:L "May I suggest that a *small* fortune—?" Truly the presence of an immortal was sharpening his wits.
>
> "Of course. But it would have to be exceedingly small. I couldn't go above $1.98."
>
> "Is that all?" Will's voice was heavy with disappointment.
>
> "I'm afraid it is. We minor gods are always pinched for funds. Perhaps a different sort of gift—"